# Rey vs. Kylo in tug of war

Tags: star-wars, the-force, the-last-jedi, kylo-ren, rey

So in *The Last Jedi* there was a scene where:

> Each of them were pulling lightsaber with the force. As a result lightsaber was destroyed, Kylo goes sleep (Kylo you loser...) and Rey flew away.

I was just wondering. What would have happened if one of them would push for a moment? Wouldn't it be clever trick? Opponent get hit with high speed object.

Comment: The *entire point* of Force pulling the object was to have it travel toward themselves at high speed so that they could catch it. If the other person stopped, then that would be just jim-dandy

Comment: Yeah, but here you would have 2 forces which can create too big speed for catching. Something like bullet. It will move faster toward you, but will you catch it? Or the Force works in other way?

Comment: This seems incredibly opinion based.

Comment: This really only works for one of them; if it was attempted. Whoever the blade was facing (I don't remember from the movie - I think the blade faced Kylo?). If the opposite stopped pulling to turn it on they would have to hope that the blade would not be flipped fast enough to be caught before it was able to be caught and used... otherwise it would just be helping the other person not only get the blade, but have it turned on and ready to strike... awful risky and as Tony Stark once said... "Not a great plan."

Comment: I'm not sure the light sabre would be travelling too fast for either of them to catch. Remember, these people are capable of deflecting shots from blasters travelling at immense speeds. The Force clearly gives them some superhuman level of reaction. On top of this, each was trying to Force-pull the sabre _into_ their hand, not just in their general direction. If one had relinquished the Force and the other was not ready, sure it might have given them a bit of a painful whack, but the consequences for the other would have been far more severe.

Answer (score 3):

Pushing for a moment **might** have been a plausible trick to try. The sudden change, and object rushing towards them might be enough to break their focus for long enough to pull the lightsaber back to you. The key-word here being might. It is a pretty big gamble that has a large backfire if it doesn't work. Also, in the symbolic battle between the light and dark in each of them, a power match is far more satisfying to watch, so as well as it not being the best tactical choice, it doesn't have the benefit of being played for the entertainment value either.

Getting hit with the lightsaber on the other hand would do nothing other than make it closer to the other person. Remember, it would only be going 2x the speed they were pulling it at, so even if their jedi reflexes were not enough to predict and or catch it (which they probably would be). At worst they would get a light bruise, and then proceed to pick up the lightsaber and kill the other person